# Testing IllegalArgumentException is not catching as expected

Tags: java, exception, junit, illegalargumentexception

I have the following testing code:

```
@Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
public void addPlayerFailureTest()    {
    playerDAO.addPlayer(null);
}
```

This code is supposed to return an `IllegalArgumentException`, and it does as expected. However, it turns the test red. This is the stacktrace:

```
ERROR  addPlayer, Player failure: 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: attempt to create merge event with null entity
    at org.hibernate.event.MergeEvent.<init>(MergeEvent.java:60)
    at org.hibernate.event.MergeEvent.<init>(MergeEvent.java:43)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:688)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:692)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.merge(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:235)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:365)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy32.merge(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:240)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy32.merge(Unknown Source)
    at fr.game.core.dao.AbstractJpaGenericDAO.update(AbstractJpaGenericDAO.java:58)
    at fr.game.core.dao.player.JPAJoueurDAO.addJoueur(JPAJoueurDAO.java:40)
    at fr.game.core.dao.player.JoueurDAOTest.addJoueurFailureTest(JoueurDAOTest.java:23)
```

I am supposed to receive this exception, yet I cannot. I met the same behavior when testing a wrong value in an `Enum`.

**Why does it make my test fail ?** Is it because the exception is thrown from such a place that it cannot be caught that way ?

**EDIT**

The `addPlayer()` method:

```
public boolean addPlayer(Player player) {
    try {
        update(player);
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Player failure : ", e);
        return false;
    }
}
```

It would have been detected before (as we would not reach the `return false` in this case), but I am taking back some old code from former devs, thus writing test cases for this particular use case.

Comment: "ERROR  addPlayer, Player failure" where does this message come from?

Comment: Is there a delegate method catching the exception, and throwing it away or wrapping it in some other type of exception?  Post the code for the addPlayer() method.

Comment: "ERROR addPlayer" comes from Hibernate, "Player failure" is a custom message. I'll post the code.

Comment: Your `addPlayer`  method catches all exceptions. If you pass in null and `update` throws an exception, I'd expect it to just return false, as that's what your code does. If your production code is as you want it to be, you should just expect that `addPlayer(null)` returns false without an exception.

Comment: the moral of the story is **never** `catch(Exception e)` it is always incorrect!

Comment: Well, I'm learning :). Taking steps by myself into mastering beautiful design and well-written code is as rough as it gets.

Comment: @YassineBadache - While you are here, you could consider using ExpectedException.html(http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/rules/ExpectedException.html) rule to ensure exceptions are thrown (and can check messages too). I have personally found it way more useful than the expected clause in the annotation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are catching the `IllegalArgumentException` (which is a subtype of `Exception`) in your `addPlayer()` method. It never reaches the test method.
What you see isn't the actual exception thrown by the test method, but the console output of `log.error("Player failure : ", e);`.

Comment: How dumb of me. Of course. Beginner's mistake. Thank you for your sharpness.